# Running pip and conda in a shell script: not found

Tags: shell, pip, conda

I am trying to run this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

git clone https://github.com/QCoDeS/Qcodes.git
cd Qcodes/
conda env create -f environment.yml
pip install qcodes
```

with the following command:

```
chmod +x qcodes 
~ ❯ sudo ./qcodes
```

And I keep getting the error

```
./qcodes: 5: ./qcodes: conda: not found
./qcodes: 6: ./qcodes: pip: not found
```

conda and pip are installed and work on the terminal. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: in conda env you should use conda, not pip, that's the purpose of conda, it's the package manager instead of pip.

Comment: I know this and there is a reason why this is done so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I forgot to remove `sudo` from the command.